# How do I generate a new page in PHP and rewrite the page URL a random string?

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to make a random URL to display user submitted content like http://www.imgur.com   ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enQt0.jpg))without any framework.

I know I need to put something in .htaccess, but I have no clue what to write.

I already have the code needed to create a random string:

```
<?php
    $seed = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_-');
    $rand = array_rand($seed, 7);
    $convert = array_map(function($n){
        global $seed;
        return $seed[$n];
    },$rand);

    $var = implode('',$convert);
    echo $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you have to learn how [**GET**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) method works.

**Description from PHP.net:**

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

**Example:**

I want to enter my website and see the double of the number from the URL using $_GET.

So i'll give you the address, for example: mywebsite.com/number.php?number=5

then in number.php file:

```
$myNumber = $_GET['number'];
echo $myNumber * 2;
```

Now, every time you enter to this URL you will see the double of the number from the URL.

To make your URL prettier, you can use **[.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)** which provide you a way to change your URL.

For example, i want to change my URL to mywebsite.com/number/5 and navigate to the same file as mywebsite.com/?number=5 did:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule     ^number/([0-9]+)/?$    number.php?number=$1
```

Comment: *"To achieve your goal you have to learn how GET method works."* - Telling them they need to learn something, is more of a comment really.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13917970)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i have changed it :)

Comment: @techspider i have changed it :)

Comment: @bnsd55 Thanks ;-) now to see what the OP has to say. *Cheers*

Comment: @bnsd55 Thanks!
 I succesfully edited the .htaccess file with a slightly different regex so It allows Text as well,
I also wrote something to retrieve the GET parameter from the database, and display the matching content. Now I only need to make a file upload system.

Comment: @David Perfect! It will be great if you can vote to the answer and mark it as the best answer for other people :)